# GREP in Adobe InDesign for function name

Tags: replace, adobe, adobe-indesign, grep-indesign

I'm looking for a grep for JavaScript function names including parenthesis.

Example: `myfunction()`

I need it to ignore jQuery events like `.on()`, `.click()`, `.width()` as well. So basically "get word before parenthesis and parenthesis but not if there is a `.` before the word". I tried different stuff like `([\l\u]())` but i can't get my head around. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match a phrase where something may not appear "before" it, use a negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!\.)\b([\l\u]+\(\))
```

One possible problem in your own attempt may have been that you only test a single character before the parentheses; another may have been you did not escape the (literal!) parentheses.

This matches `myfunction()` and even `myFunction()`, but nothing more. A larger commonly used set of characters in function names would be:

```
(?<!\.)\b([_\l\u]\w*\(\))
```

Note that this ignores any and all *arguments* that may appear inside the parentheses (as per your specification, or so it would seem). Unfortunately, that is not easily added since you can *not* match "matching parentheses" with a single GREP.

Comment: Thanks you for your reply! Unfortunately both of your solutions still match jQuery events. So if I would like to make the function names bold, i get this result: .w **idth()**

Comment: I forgot to add a compulsory "word break". Edited answer.